# How can I know NSWindow was closed using the close button ?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Is there an easy way to know when a NSWindow was closed using the close button (of the window title bar) .

Using `NSWindowDelegate` and the `windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification` method I get notification of each closing. But how can I know the closing request was send by the close button

Comment: Is your close button custom? do you run any other action on it?

Comment: nope it's the red close button in the top left corner of a standard NSWindow.

Comment: maybe you can subclass NSWindow to try and override the performClose method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `[yourWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton]` to find the close button, then change its target and action to a custom method.